# Overheating in an dual-boot system (windows 8+Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, overheating, fan, acpi

Precisely, I would like to know if booting windows 8 through GRUB can affect in any way the global performance (CPU/GPU benchmarks, cooling efficiency etc...) in both Windows and Ubuntu 14.04 ...

I have noticed a huge performance drop in both OS since installing Ubuntu in dual boot mode (I had previously tested both Os separately on the same machine). Even in high Temp (+99°C) the fans don't seem to speed up (thus I don't think it's a hardware issue)

I'm using an Acer Aspire 5755G with legacy BIOS. I suspect GRUB since I have overridden acpi_os=default to acpi_os=linux, which got the backlight running.

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue. When  you said 'I had previously tested both...' does that mean you completely wiped out Windows at one point? If so, it's possible that the proper driver was never installed that controls the fans as well as the drivers for the GPU/CPU/Chipset. If you still have your recovery disks, I'd try using those to recover windows 8 from scratch. If not, check Acer's website for the drivers and try to update from there. As a last case scenario go to the CPU/GPU/Chipset manufacturer's website and download the drivers from there

Comment: Yes I wiped out windows and installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 14.04 sitting alone in the HDD then installed the proprer drivers (Using Nvidia Prime package) along side 'thermald' and 'intel p-state'... the System was hot but not excessively overheated. And I recovered Windows 8 alone, with all drivers installed and up to date, GPU temp never excedded 79° even in full load scenarios.... Thanks for your answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

GRUB Has **NOTHING** to do with Overheating/Performance, GRUB Just Boot's up the Partition and Blows away, it's execution time Counted in seconds.

About the FAN Speed, Check BIOS Settings they might be reset which what happened to me at a time for unknown Reason, Also Try Restoring Defaults for BIOS.

Otherwise Check Your Drivers and make sure they are properly Installed and Up-To Date

Comment: Thanks, gonna have to reset back to previous BIOS versions and see how It works out

Comment: Incorrecct.  GRUB has everything to do with overheating. Grub sets up a poll loop and will burn your internal components until your PC becomes a brick if it is left open for a long time, even on a modern machine.  You should edit your answer to include the warning.  If you can merge the answers, I can also delete my answer and give you a +1.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT LEAVE GRUB OPEN! IT MIGHT CERTAINLY CAUSE MAJOR COMPONENT DAMAGE! IF YOU ARE ALTERING A GRUB BOOT COMMAND, BE PREPARED TO COMPLETELY FINISH THE ALTERATION AND BOOT BEFORE STOPPING; IF YOU ARE INTERRUPTED, TURN OFF THE COMPUTER IMMEDIATELY BY PRESSING AND HOLDING THE POWER BUTTON!

Figure out what you want to do in grub before you use it, just to be safe. This danger is caused by a poll loop.

An advanced understanding would be required to fix this: it is not editing TIMEOUT because that only works prior to user input: according to GRUB support, there is no current working method to fix this.